# is it possible to update .properties files from batch script?

Tags: batch-file, jenkins

is it possible to update .properties files from batch script?

We have a external system which reads one configuration properties files and based on that it is doing some task. Our plan is to accept some dynamic values(like version number etc.) from user input(Jenkins parametrized build) and update those new values in existing config.properties file.

Please help!

Comment: Yes, you can edit a text properties file, writing a new one and replacing the old one.  `repl.bat` is a stream editing tool much like SED and can help with the file edits.

Answer (score -1):

If I'm understanding correctly, yes, I do something similar. JobA feeds properties to JobB. 
JobA runs a task that creates an Amazon EC2 instance. The public URL is detected after instance creation, and I write that to an output.properties file. That file is saved to the jenkins node running JobA.

In Post-build Actions, use "Trigger parameterized build on other projects." -- from the Parameterized Trigger Plugin https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin --

"Projects to build" is JobB.

In "Parameters from properties file," point it at the output.properties file (relative to the workspace).

When JobB is triggered it'll use that file just like any other properties file, so you have a downstream job that's able to consume relatively random output from an upstream job.

```
[jenkins@burl-aet-jenk01 poc]$ cat output.properties
INSTANCE_HOSTNAME = ec2-54-84-37-183.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

Comment: such a bad answer .. doesn't answer anything about how the OP can write the output to the properties file inside windows bat !